# NearestNeighbor producing bad quality tiles

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache, nearest-neighbor

I have been using Bicubic interpolation to render some basemaps because this produced good results. This is what I get when using Bicubic:
[image]

However, when using Nearest Neighbor interpolation, a white line pattern shows up. So lines and labels seem to be "split". This is only a slight change but it makes the map pretty much unreadable:

[image]

I know that theoretically, Bicubic produces better results than NearestNeighbor. However, differences in my case are too big and my guess is that I am doing something wrong in the layer setup that generates the rendering issue when using Nearest Neighbor.

If possible, I would like to use NearestNeighbor because it requires less resources.

Can anybody provide some feedback on what I'm doing wrong with this basemap?

P.S. Edit: Have removed all references to GeoWebCache in this question because I realized that the issue has nothing to do with GWC but with the interpolation method itself.

Comment: Just to be sure, how do you check the results? If you load the basemap in a GIS viewer using a different CRS the images will be reprojected client side, giving similar results. It's best practice to have all source data in the same coordinate system to prevent this. If not possible you should reproject the data, not the basemap.

Comment: I'm using the Layer Preview and Preview function from cached layers section, and I load it to a specific GIS viewer build in OpenLayers. Results are the same independently of the viewer, and both layers and viewers use 27700 CRS